# R error “Can't join on … because of incompatible types (list / list)”

Tags: r, dataframe, self-join

I'm aware that questions with similar error codes have been asked, but our problem is not answered so far.

Problem: self join of dataframe on itself by a column that has lists as content.

**DATA**:

```
bsp_fn <- c("1","2","3","4","5")
bsp_liste1 <- list(list("a","b","c"),list("a","b"),list("a","c"),list("a","b","c"),list("b","c"))
bsp_df <- tibble(bsp_fn,bsp_liste1)
```

**PROBLEM**:

```
bsp_df %>% inner_join(bsp_df,by="bsp_liste1") 

Error: Can't join on'bsp_liste1' x 'bsp_liste1' because of incompatible types (list / list)
```

**QUESTION**:

Can I join "by comparison" of the lists? Since the list "a","b","c" appears twice, I would expect a match here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can `join` using lists as `by`, I think `by` has to be an atomic data structure. However, this works:

```
bsp_df %>%
  mutate(ID = paste0(unlist(bsp_liste1), collapse="")) %>% 
  inner_join(bsp_df %>% mutate(ID = paste0(unlist(bsp_liste1), collapse="")),by="ID")
```

Comment: This matches every row with every other row and is not the expected behaviour. I would expect only one match. (row 1 and row 4)

Comment: But your example: `bsp_df %>% inner_join(bsp_df,by="bsp_liste1") ` joins `bsp_df` on itself?! Wouldn't we expect **all** rows to match?

Comment: No, since only the lists of row 1 and row 4 are the same I would only expect a match here. Also unlisting lists to character strings makes lists in uneven order incomparable, or not?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. But if we `join` a data.frame on itself, **all** rows will be matched! I don't understand what you mean with "since only the lists of row 1 and row 4 are the same I would only expect a match here" - thats not how `join` works. And what do you mean by `uneven order` ?

Answer (score 0):

NOT an Answer, rather a comment (can't comment because of insufficient reputation)

I think what @Sedir means is the following:

```
bsp_df %>%
     group_by(bsp_fn) %>% 
     mutate(ID = paste0(unlist(bsp_liste1), collapse="")) %>% 
     inner_join(bsp_df %>% group_by(bsp_fn) %>% mutate(ID = paste0(unlist(bsp_liste1), collapse="")),by="ID")
```

which matches 1-1 and 1-4, 2-2, 3-3, 4-1, 4-4, 5-5. But still, it only works in the "right" order, i.e. "abc"; "cba" would not match.